# ORACLE - Short CIrcuit "OR" operator: do not work?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, short-circuiting, or-operator

I'm very bewildered because I don't understand Oracle planning execution of my query.
This is the original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
ON TI.INDEX1 = T2.INDEX1
WHERE
        T1.C1 LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:param1, '%'))
    AND T2.C2 LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:param2, '%'))
```

This query takes 60 seconds for result (I'm using null value for both parameters).

I tied to find out the problem and I've discovered that T2.C2 was the problem.
Same query without second where condition takes 15 seconds, so, i've trasformed like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
ON TI.INDEX1 = T2.INDEX1
WHERE
        (:param1 IS NULL OR T1.C1 LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:param1, '%')))
    AND (:param2 IS NULL OR T2.C2 LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:param2, '%')))
```

This is executioin plan:
[image: Execution plan with 2 condition]

nothing has changed!!!!
With both where clauses query takes 60 seconds!!!

I tied this:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
ON TI.INDEX1 = T2.INDEX1
WHERE
        (:param1 IS NULL OR T1.C1 LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:param1, '%')))
    AND (:param2 IS NULL)
```

It's takes 15 seconds.
[image: Execution plan with 1 condition]

Can anyone explain how to improve this query?
Can someone help me understand why short circuit does not work?

Comment: How about executions plans?

Comment: Also those queries are different, because the first one will not match any rows where either T1.C1 or T2.C2 are null, whereas the second one will.

Comment: Oracle doesn't, and doesn't claim to, short circuit as you seem to expect in SQL. (It does in PL/SQL, but that's different). The optimiser decides how and when to apply the logic, and may transform what you wrote to achieve that.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Why? You'll get all rows where c1 is not null and c2 is not null

Comment: I've added execution plans

Comment: Oracle does in fact short-circuit the evaluation of a predicate with `OR`, but not the way you (@GlaucoCucchiar) expect: the predicate must be evaluated for each row, but it will short-circuit for each row, so `:param2 IS NULL` will be evaluated for each row and, if it _is_ `NULL`, `T2.C2 LIKE CONCAT...` will _not_ be evaluated for that row.

Comment: @mustaccio: ok, but why 1st query takes 60 seconds and 2nd only 15? both query has (:param2 IS NULL) clause and :param2 is always NULL